# Jenkins Pipelines: How to use withCredentials() from a shared-variable script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to use a `withCredentials()` block in a shared-variable ("vars/") script rather than directly in the Jenkins pipeline because this is a lower-level semantic of a particular library, and also may or may not be required depending on the situation. However, `withCredentials` (or, at least, that signature of it) doesn't appear to be in scope.

script:

```
def credentials = [
    [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '6a55c310-aaf9-4822-bf41-5500cd82af4e', passwordVariable: 'GERRIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GERRIT_USERNAME'],
    [$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: 'SVC_SWREGISTRY_PASSWORD', variable: 'SVC_SWREGISTRY_PASSWORD']
]

withCredentials(credentials) {
// ...
}
```

Console:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: BuildagentInstallAndRun.withCredentials() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [[[$class:UsernamePasswordMultiBinding, credentialsId:6a55c310-aaf9-4822-bf41-5500cd82af4e, ...], ...], ...]
```

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: You probably need to import the credentials class or wrap it inside of pipeline code. I have not done something like the former before, but the latter is well documented.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using a shared library rather than a shared variable, but I guess it is a similar situation.
I'm not using the `$class` parameter, but i'm calling directly one of the functions suggested by the pipeline snippet generator. You can have a list [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/). In the example below, I use the `usernameColonPassword` binding.
In the pipeline, I instantiate the class utilities and I pass `this` to the constructor. Then, in the library, I use the `step` object to access the pipeline steps (such as `withCredentials` or `usernameColonPassword`).

```
class Utilities implements Serializable {
    def steps
    Utilities(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }
    def doArchiveToNexus(String credentials, String artifact, String artifact_registry_path){
        try {
            this.steps.withCredentials([steps.usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: credentials, variable: 'JENKINS_USER')]) {
                this.steps.sh "curl --user " + '${JENKINS_USER}' + " --upload-file ${artifact} ${artifact_registry_path}"
            }
        } catch (error){
            this.steps.echo error.getMessage()
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do the same and I have to declare a constructor with 2 parameters: 'steps' and 'env'. Then for using variable JENKINS_USER I have to write "${env.JENKINS_USER}" instead of '${JENKINS_USER}'. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @Max you can use variable JENKINS_USER like "${this.steps.env.JENKINS_USER}", therefore 'env' parameter can be omited

Answer (score 5):

You can try following:

```
import jenkins.model.*

credentialsId = '6a55c310-aaf9-4822-bf41-5500cd82af4e'

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
  com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null ).find{
    it.id == credentialsId}

println creds.username 
println creds.password
```

But it is not secure, everything will be in console log

Answer (score 2):

I was able to obtain credentials inside the shared library with proper passwords masking with such code:

```
class Utilities implements Serializable {
def steps
Utilities(steps) {
    this.steps = steps
}
def execute() {
    this.steps.withCredentials(
            bindings: [
                this.steps.usernameColonPassword(
                    credentialsId: this.credentialsId, 
                    variable: "unameColonPwd")
            ]) {
        this.steps.sh "echo {this.steps.env.unameColonPwd}"
    }
}
```